# Uncaught TypeError: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property Name

Tags: lightning-web-components

Am not doing anything fancy, just trying to update a field on Contact in JS of LWC but getting this exception.

`Uncaught TypeError: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property 'Name'
throws at mydomain/auraFW/javascript/mhontaYdOya4Y_lBu7v9yg/aura_prod.js:2:27687`

HTML Code:

```
<template>

    <template if:true={wiredContact}>

        {wiredContact.Name}

        <lightning-input value={wiredContact.Name} onchange={updateName}></lightning-input>
    </template>

</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement ,wire,track,api } from 'lwc';
import myContact from "@salesforce/apex/ContactController.fetchContact";

export default class Myrefreshapextest extends LightningElement {


 @track wiredContact;

 @wire (myContact)
        fetchedContact({error, data}){
            if(data){
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                this.wiredContact = data;
            }else if (error){
                console.log(error);
            }
    }

    updateName (event){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(event.detail.value));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.wiredContact));
        this.wiredContact.Name = event.detail.value;
    }

}
```

Apex:

```
public class ContactController {

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Contact fetchContact(){
        return [SELECT Id,Name FROM COntact LIMIT  1];
    }
}
```

On top of my head, am not doing anything wrong, anyone has idea what's wrong with my code?

When I print `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.wiredContact));` I get old values so am pretty sure it exists.

I tried with @track and @api, but same response. Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: Do you get same issue when you use the individual field names viz., `FirstName`?

Comment: Same error `Uncaught TypeError: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property 'FirstName'
throws at` its same error doesnt matter if its normal contact or personAccountContact.

Comment: I got the error (not exactly the same) but was able to replicate. Seems like you cannot set a value directly to the property instead recreate the JSON and then assign. E.g., `this.wiredContact = ["Name:" + event.detail.value];` this worked. Still trying to figure out.

Comment: @JayantDas It's a design feature. One that I'm pretty sure isn't documented.

Comment: @sfdcfox I just saw the behavior you mentioned just by *trying it out*, and it worked, even though my format above is not JSON, but I was intending that.

Comment: @sfdcfox And thankfully it seems it is documented, referred in my answer.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Cached items are set as read-only (because otherwise you could corrupt the cache). If you want a modifiable object, you need to clone it.

```
this.wiredContact = Object.assign({}, data);
```

Based on comments, you can also use the rest parameter syntax in LWC:

```
this.wiredContact = {...data};
```

If you don't care about some mobile browsers, and you're using [Lightning Web Security](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/lws-distortion-viewer) instead of [Locker Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer), you can also use the [`structuredClone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) function, which can handle even recursive structures and other things that the `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value))` trick doesn't support. You can check the status of structuredClone on [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/?search=structured%20clone).

Comment: +1 for [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). Didn't know something like this existed.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox. You are truly a  Javascript wizard.

Comment: @JayantDas In ES6, the syntactic sugar is: `this.wiredContact = {...data};`

Comment: @tsalb Thanks for sharing. I now recollect coming it across on one of Pranay’s another [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/253717/how-to-convey-lwcs-complex-reactive-property-back-to-markup)

Comment: @tsalb I knew `...` could be used as a rest parameter, I didn't actually know it works the way you mentioned. Thanks for teaching me something new!

Comment: Yeah it beats doing the cloning dance when I want some mutable data from some unmutable stream, I actually used a lot of `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` in aura and forgot about `Object.assign()` hah. FYI, they are two sides of the same coin: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread

Comment: Just to let you guys know, using this method corrupts the cache, thus refreshApex does not work,

Comment: @PranayJaiswal I suspect something else is going on. The cache can't be affected, because it's a cloned object. I'd be happy to write a gist for you if you'd like.

Comment: One thing to note is that if the returned object is a complex one (for example an object with nested objects) it seems the nested objects are not "cloned" since trying to modify them will result is the same immutable error. In such case, the `Object.assign` and `{...data}` doesn't seem to do the trick, only `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))`

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, I have tried both of the syntax as mention above  this.wiredContact = Object.assign({}, data); and this.wiredContact = {...data}; (with curly and square bracket) both of them didn't work, I would be highly thankful if you will take look on my thread https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/283536/uncaught-typeerror-set-on-proxy-trap-returned-falsish-for-property-percenta

Comment: @jonathanwiesel, thanks for the nested complex note, this seems to be an issue as shallow copy will not work on nested complex(yet) so have to use as you suggested JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))..

Comment: @jonathanwiesel indeed `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))` is the solution when working with complex and nested arrays, it will be helpful if your comment was added as an answer to find it more easily

Comment: If you ***only*** wanted to add/update the `Name` property, is there a more concise way than `this.wiredContact = Object.assign({}, this.wiredContact, {Name: 'Joe'})`?

Comment: @jbyrd `this.wiredContact = {...this.wiredContact, Name: 'Joe'}`

Comment: `structuredClone()` [does only work under Lightning Web Security](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/lws-distortion-viewer), not under [Locker Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer).

Comment: @FelixvanHove I've been writing LWC long enough I forgot to check the LS API docs, lol. Well, soon enough everyone will be on LWS anyways, but I'll amend that bit.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I could find from the [documentation for wired service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about) and that seems to be the case here (emphasis mine).

> The wire service provisions an **immutable stream of data** to the component

So it most likely seems that when trying to set the values directly using `this.wiredContact.Name`, because of it's read only property, the values are not getting set.

However if you try to create a new data and then assign it to `this.wiredContact`, it works:

```
this.wiredContact = "{Name:" + event.detail.value + "}";
```

Comment: This solution presumes only one field. If you have multiple fields, you must remember to encode all of them or lose data. The solution I presented avoids this problem by copying everything on initialization, leaving the variable free to be modified in all other function calls.

Comment: Yeah, this was a more direct answer to the problem that Pranay had mentioned. I am not really good at JS, so didn't even know how to do so unless you mentioned.

Comment: +1 thanks for linking documentation. This was freaking me out.

Comment: I started looking only when @sfdcfox mentioned it was possibly not :) But at least it is mentioned. Easy to miss!

Answer (score 2):

For nested Objects I use two recursive functions :

```
const setNestedKey = (obj, path, value) => {

    if (path.length === 1) {
        obj = {...obj, [path] : value}
        return obj
    }
        return setNestedKey(obj[path[0]], path.slice(1), value)
    }

const assignObject = (obj, path, value) => {

    let newObj = setNestedKey(obj, path, value);
    if (path.length === 1) {
        return newObj;
    } 
    path.pop();
    return assignObject(obj, path, newObj);

}
```

Comment: Seems to imply you have "path" stored as an array?  Or maybe I'm missing something.  Wondering if you can explain how you're creating and binding that variable to input components.

Comment: Yes, "path" must be an array. I've improved it :

Comment: Yes, "path" must be an array. You can add this line in the assignObject function :  `let keys = Array.isArray(path) ? path : path.split('.'); `to manage a string or an array. In my LWC, I have to set nested property of complex objects. i.e, to set p3 of `myObj = { p1: v1, { p2 : v2, {p3: v3}}} `the usage is `myObj = assign(myObj, 'p1.p2.p3', value);` I've also improve the function to work with array property.

Comment: Sorry : `myObj = { p1: { p2 : {p3: v3}}} `

Answer (score 2):

Cached items read only, you need to create a new deep copy of the json object

```
this.wiredContact = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to avoid getting this error is by updating the way you call your Apex method. So instead of using the `@wire` decorator, you can just explicitly call your Apex method within the `connectedCallback()` lifecycle hook and removing the `(cacheable=true)` annotation from your Apex controller method. So your updated files would look like this:

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track, api } from 'lwc';
import myContact from "@salesforce/apex/ContactController.fetchContact";

export default class Myrefreshapextest extends LightningElement {

     connectedCallback() {
        myContact()
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }

    //More code...

}
```

APEX:

```
public class ContactController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Contact fetchContact(){
        return [SELECT Id,Name FROM COntact LIMIT  1];
    }
}
```

Comment: But then I won't be able to use wire and have access to cached data?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Without those decorators and annotations, your data won't be cached

Answer (score 0):

With arrays, you can use the map function and clone the object. An example customizing columns for use in a lightning datatable where data is wired return result.

```
const contacts = data.map((contact) => ({
    ...contact,
    OwnerName: contact.Owner.Name,
    Industry: contact.Account.Industry
}));
this.contacts = contacts;
```

Adding to this as I ran into this scenario. I wanted to update the a record in an array without calling refresh apex. This has worked consistently so far. There may be another way more succinct.

```
updateRecord(recordInput)
.then((result) => {
    // Clone data
    const data = [...this._data];
    this._data = [];
    const index = data.findIndex((row) => row.Id === result.id);
    // Clone row (object)
    const row = {...data[index]};
    // Set some values
    row.Industry = "Banking";
    row.AccountSource = "Partner";
    // Replace row
    data.splice(index, 1, row);
    // Set data
    this._data = data;
    this.dispatchEvent(
        new ShowToastEvent({
            title: "Success",
            message: "Account updated",
            variant: "success"
        })
    );
})
.catch((error) => {
    this.dispatchEvent(
        new ShowToastEvent({
            title: "Error Updating Account",
            message: reduceErrors(error).join(", "),
            variant: "error",
            mode: "sticky"
        })
    );
})
```