# Lightning Web Component Custom Sorting

Tags: lightning-web-components, sort

Using the below JS method for the custom sorting to work on a lightning data table. The same works perfectly in aura frame work. I suspect key() doesn't work in lwc. Documentation didn't help much. Can someone suggest what's going wrong with below piece.

```
updateColumnSorting(event) {
    var fieldName = event.detail.fieldName;
    var sortDirection = event.detail.sortDirection;
    this.sortedBy = fieldName;
    this.sortedDirection = sortDirection;
    var reverse = sortDirection !== 'asc';
    var dataToSort = this.data;
    dataToSort.sort(this.sortBy(fieldName, reverse));
    this.data = dataToSort;
}

sortBy(field, reverse, primer) {
    var key = primer ?
            function(x) {return primer(x.hasOwnProperty(field) ? (typeof x[field] === 'text' ? x[field].toLowerCase() : x[field]) : 'aaa')} :
            function(x) {return x.hasOwnProperty(field) ? (typeof x[field] === 'text' ? x[field].toLowerCase() : x[field]) : 'aaa'};
        reverse = !reverse ? 1 : -1;
        return function (a, b) {            
            return a = key(a), b = key(b), reverse * ((a > b) - (b > a));
        }

}
```

Error LOG

> [NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script error.
>   newHandler()@https://static.lightning.force.com/cs94/auraFW/javascript/pxtF0ZdGYF-z00XsmRUcGQ/aura_proddebug.js:46041:14
>   {anonymous}()@https://static.lightning.force.com/cs94/auraFW/javascript/pxtF0ZdGYF-z00XsmRUcGQ/aura_proddebug.js:46057:25
>   vo.dispatchEvent()@https://static.lightning.force.com/cs94/auraFW/javascript/pxtF0ZdGYF-z00XsmRUcGQ/aura_proddebug.js:6810:34
>   vo.fireSortedColumnChange()@https://efficiency-computing-5859-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/components/lightning/datatable.js:11:19414 vo.handleUpdateColumnSort()@https://efficiency-computing-5859-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/components/lightning/datatable.js:11:19042

Comment: if you debug this part, `dataToSort.sort(this.sortBy(fieldName, reverse));`, what do you notice? can you update your post with additional troubleshooting? thanks

Comment: Error: 
-----
TypeError: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property '0'
LINE:
------
d.sort(this.sortBy(b,"asc"!==c)

Comment: @sfdcfox I see your comments and new to lightning development [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/256761/uncaught-typeerror-set-on-proxy-trap-returned-falsish-for-property-name/256772#256772) can you please advise what should be the fix

Comment: Thanks everyone for looking. Couple of actions i took which helped resolve the issue

a. Removed the cacheable flag from controller method
b. de-serialized the data and pass it back at the end of event