# LWC | Get modified values of a list in javascript controller

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I am having a lightning web component which iterates over a list and displays values in a list

HTML:

```
<template>
<template for:each={myList} for:item="myRecord">
    <div class="slds-truncate" title={rowSip.rowSIP.E2E_Volume_Target_FFE__c}>
        <lightning-input type="text"  name="input2" value={myRecord.Name} onchange={updateValues}></lightning-input>
    </div>
</template>
```

Javascript:

```
updateValues(event) {
    console.log(this.myList);
}
```

**Problem:**

In the 'updateValues' , I am consoling the list. But it has the old value.

**Expected:**

The list should give the modified value.

What could be the problem ? Or how to get the updated list values in Javascript ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way binding, thus you have to update the element in your list yourself. You can do that defining an attribute in your `lightning-input` and do array.find in the orignal list and then update that selected element.

```
<template>
    <template for:each={myList} for:item="myRecord">


        <lightning-input type="text" key={myRecord.Id} data-id={myRecord.Id} name="input2"  value={myRecord.Name} onchange={updateValues}></lightning-input>

    </template>
</template>
```

JS:

```
@track myList = [{Name: "MEOW" ,Id : 'I1'} , {Name: "Bark" ,Id : 'I2'}];



    updateValues(event){
        let foundelement = this.myList.find(ele => ele.Id == event.target.dataset.id);
        foundelement.Name = event.target.value;
        this.myList = [...this.myList];

        console.table(JSON.stringify(this.myList));



    }
```

Comment: console.log(this.myList); is outputting the old value. How to get the new value ?

Comment: there is no two way binding, you have to manually edit list and update the value for your index.

Comment: How can I atleast get the selected row ?

Comment: @JunaidPKhader updated answer.

Comment: Yes I saw this. But somehow, this is not working for me. let foundelement = this.myList.find(ele => ele.Id == event.target.dataset.id);

Comment: Have you added data-id in the lightning-input

Comment: Thanks Pranay. I am able to find the corresponding element. But I am getting an error when I am setting the value. The error is "['set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property 'fieldname'] "

Comment: @JunaidPKhader you have to refer this?
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/256761/uncaught-typeerror-set-on-proxy-trap-returned-falsish-for-property-name