# Calling Apex only fails when set (cachable=true)

Tags: apex, javascript, lightning-web-components, debugging

I have an Account `List Lightning Web Component` (LWC) that is calling a `(cachable=true)` Controller method on load and when someone in the UI changes a filter string. The always works as long as the result list is not empty. If empty it renders correctly but then shows this obscure message:

> [NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script error.
>   a()@https://static.lightning.force.com/cs83/auraFW/javascript/dOMRLHt4yryfVjId3qhSww/aura_prod.js:903:85
>   {anonymous}()@https://static.lightning.force.com/cs83/auraFW/javascript/dOMRLHt4yryfVjId3qhSww/aura_prod.js:903:278
>   r.dispatchEvent()@https://static.lightning.force.com/cs83/auraFW/javascript/dOMRLHt4yryfVjId3qhSww/aura_prod.js:12:5396
>   r.dispatchSelect()@https://innovation-computing-9921-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/components/interop/buttonMenu.js:2:9451
>   r.handleMenuItemPrivateSelect()@https://innovation-computing-9921-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/components/interop/buttonMenu.js:2:9410

When I remove the `(cachable=true)` it always works.

**Apex**

```
public with sharing class AccountListCtrl {

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Api.AccountWrapper> getAccounts(String filter) {
        List<Api.AccountWrapper> result = new List<Api.AccountWrapper>();

        try {
            result = ...
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            new AuraHandledException()...
        }

        return result;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
            <lightning-button-menu slot="actions" onselect={changeFilter} icon-name="utility:filter" menu-alignment="right" variant="border-filled">
                <lightning-menu-item value="myAccount" label="My Accounts"></lightning-menu-item>
                <lightning-menu-item value="teamAccounts" label="Team Accounts"></lightning-menu-item>
            </lightning-button-menu>
            ...
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**JS**

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from "lwc";

import getAccounts from "@salesforce/apex/AccountCtrl.getAccounts";

export default class TaskList extends LightningElement {

    @track accounts = [];

    connectedCallback() {
        this.loadAccounts("myAccounts");
    }

    changeFilter(event) {
        this.loadAccounts(event.detail.value);
    }

    loadAccounts(filter) {
        getProcesses({ filter: filter })
            .then((result) => {
                this.accounts = result;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                ...
            })
            .finally(() => {
                ...
            });
    }
}
```

> Note: When I remove the (cachable=true) it doesn't fail.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in a javascript debugger, such as in Chrome? Usually inspecting the variables there reveals the issue.

Comment: Sure, but it happend somewhere between the lines. When I take a way the cacchable=true it doesn't fail.

Comment: what is triggering `changeFilter`? Error is apparently coming from buttonMenu according to your error stack trace. Can you show that code?

Comment: Are you trying to do anything that is invalidating the cache?
Something like: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/256761/uncaught-typeerror-set-on-proxy-trap-returned-falsish-for-property-name

Comment: You mean because I use cachable I can't reassign the account array?

Comment: @RobertSösemann yeah sorta, you have to break and re-create your array.

Comment: I guess I can keep @track processes = []; but have to replace this.processes = result with this.processes = Object.assign(this.processes, ...result);?!

Comment: @RobertSösemann I can see, you are not using @wire, that means you are not getting the advantage of cacheable. You are calling everything imperatively, I would use it without cacheable= true. .. That being said, if you wanna do it , it would look a lot like

`this.processes= [... result];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, lwc works on the concept of mutable objects. So, when you are getting the response from apex in **result**, then make sure you assign a copy of it in your lwc variable since that the response returned cannot be altered.
try using `this.accounts = [...result];` and cacheable =true.

Thanks