# Creating Clickable URLS in Lightning Datatable

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I have a requirement to create a Lightning Datatable that shows closed activities related to accounts. I would like the user to be able to click on the account name and go to the record. I have tried to implement [David Reed's solution](https://www.ktema.org/2018/10/22/lightning-data-table-record-link/). This is returning a "proxy trap error"  I found a [previous thread here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/256761/uncaught-typeerror-set-on-proxy-trap-returned-falsish-for-property-name). But when I attempted to close the data with 
 The value for the foreach in the console log is

```
called create url function value of param = [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
modules/c/ba_EIMA_ClosedRelationshipGroupActivities.js:4 in for each function
aura_prod.js:826 TypeError: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property 'accountURL'
```

And sample data for the Accounts property from the log is:

```
value of accounts = [{"accountId":"0013C00000Bkh6EQAR","accountName":"EIMA TEST HK1","activityStatus":"Not Started","closeDate":"2019-01-29","isTask":true,"subject":"Call"},{"accountId":"0013C00000Bkh6EQAR","accountName":"EIMA TEST HK1","activityStatus":"Not Started","isTask":true,"subject":"Very Important Task"},{"accountId":"0013C00000Bkh6EQAR","accountName":"EIMA TEST HK1","activityStatus":"Not Started","closeDate":"2019-01-01","isTask":true,"subject":"Follow-up"},{"accountId":"0013C00000C4PFBQA3","accountName":"EIMA TEST HK 2","activityStatus":"Not Started","isTask":true,"subject":"Call"}]
```

```
this.accounts = Object.assign({}, data);
```

Everything in my data table disappeared.

Below is my JS file.

```
@api recordId;
    @track accounts;
    @track error;
    @track sortBy;
    @track sortDirection;

{ label: 'Account Name', fieldName: 'accountURL', sortable: "true", type: "url", typeAttributes: {
                label: {
                    fieldName: 'accountName'
                }
            },
            target: '_self'
        },
        {label: 'Task', fieldName: 'isTask', type: 'boolean', sortable: "true"},
        //{ label: 'Id', fieldName: 'accountId' },
        {label: 'Due Date', fieldName: 'closeDate', type: 'date', sortable: "true"},
        {label: 'Status', fieldName: 'activityStatus', type: 'text', sortable: "true"},

 @wire(getClosedActivities, {groupId: '$recordId'})
    activities({error, data}) {
        if (data) {
            this.accounts = data;
            this.createAccountURL(this.accounts);
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.accounts = undefined;
        }
    };
createAccountURL(accounts){
            console.log('called create url function value of param = '  + this.accounts);

        accounts.forEach(function (account) {
            console.log('in for each function');
            account['accountURL'] = '/lightning/r/Account' + account['accountId'] + '/view';
            console.log(' value of account URL '  + account.accountURL);

        });
        console.log(`value of accounts = ${JSON.stringify(this.accounts)}`);
    }
```

Below is the Apex controller

```
 @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static List<ActivityWrapper> getClosedActivities(String groupId){
        System.debug('closed activities called');
        List<String> resultList = new List<String>();
        Set<Id> accountIds = getAccountIds(groupId);
        List<ActivityWrapper> openActivityWrappers = new List<ActivityWrapper>();

        List<Account> closedActivities = [SELECT Id, Name,
        (SELECT ActivityDate, Account.Name, Account.Id, Subject, IsTask, WhatId, Description, EndDateTime,
                Status, Priority, APX_Assigned_To_Name__c, APX_Assigned_To_User__c
        from ActivityHistories) FROM Account where Id =: accountIds];
        System.debug(closedActivities);

        for (Account a : closedActivities ){
            resultList.add(a.Name);
            for(ActivityHistory activity : a.ActivityHistories){
                System.debug('values in the loop = ' + activity);
                BA_EIMA_activityController.ActivityWrapper wrapper = new BA_EIMA_activityController.ActivityWrapper(
                        a.Id, a.Name, activity.Subject, activity.Status, activity.IsTask, activity.ActivityDate,
                        activity.APX_Assigned_To_User__c
                );
                openActivityWrappers.add(wrapper);
            }
        }
        System.debug('value in wrapper = ' + openActivityWrappers);
        System.debug('value from result list = ' + resultList);
        return openActivityWrappers;
    }
     public class ActivityWrapper {
         @AuraEnabled
        public Id  accountId {get; set;}
         @AuraEnabled
        public String accountName {get; set;}
         @AuraEnabled
        public String subject {get; set;}
         @AuraEnabled
        public String activityStatus {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public Boolean isTask{get; set;}
         @AuraEnabled
        public Date closeDate {get; set;}
         @AuraEnabled
         public String assignedTo {get; set;}

        public ActivityWrapper(String accountId, String accountName, String subject, String activityStatus,
                Boolean isTask, Date closeDate, String assignedTo){
            this.accountId = accountId; this.accountName = accountName; this.subject = subject;
            this.isTask = isTask; this.activityStatus = activityStatus; this.closeDate = closeDate;
            this.assignedTo = assignedTo;
       }
    }
```

Comment: mind scoping down where the issue might be? is the server returning the appropriate data? is it a client side issue? can you create a minimal reproduce-able code sample?

Comment: Hi glls, I do have all the data that I want in the table. Not sure what to do for a reproducible code sample. Are you asking for the return data from the debug or console.log?

Comment: In the console log what I see for the forEach method on the client is: create url function value of param = [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
modules/c/ba_EIMA_ClosedRelationshipGroupActivities.js:4 in for each function
aura_prod.js:826 TypeError: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property 'accountURL'

Comment: please update you post =) otherwise this is going to be a very long thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what but this function in the JS worked.

```
@wire(getClosedActivities, {groupId: '$recordId'})
    activities({error, data}) {
        if (data) {
            let nameURL;
            this.accounts = data.map(row => {
                nameURL = `/${row.accountId}`
                console.log('name url = ' + nameURL);
                return {...row, nameURL}

            });
            this.error = undefined;
```