# Lightning web Component : Modify the Particular property in the incoming array in child component

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

Hi i am trying to modify the particular component  in the child array but getting the particular error

try is the incoming array from parent.

```
1 @track sethg;
2 this.sethg = this.try.findIndex(item => item.ter === event.detail.ter);

3 this.try[this.sethg].booleanvariable = false;
```

on line 3 i am trying to make the incoming value as false ,
getting below error can anyone find out the possible way to set the value.

```
['set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property 'booleanvariable ']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught TypeError: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property Name](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/256761/uncaught-typeerror-set-on-proxy-trap-returned-falsish-for-property-name)

Answer (score 0):

Data passed from parent component is immutable, i.e. you can not change its value. However, you can deep clone it and make it mutable before changing the value.

```
this.try = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.try));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, the data passed from parent component is immutable.
I would suggest you not to change the value of it rather create a new variable called tryPrivate and do the following

```
@api
get try(){
return _try
}

set try(value){
this.tryPrivate = {..value} (if object) or [...value] (if array)
this._try=value;
}
```

Now, you are free to use the variable tryPrivate in child component and can edit it anytime in js.

Thanks